# Will ubuntu be able to detect windows if prevous grub got scraped?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I was wondering if I messed up my boot-loader by trying to install arch along with the current set up, will I be able to get grub to detect windows 10 again if i just reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: So you have Windows and Ubuntu installed and tried do install Arch Linux in addition to the other two?

Comment: Do not "mess up". Install them properly and you will get windows 10 entry in GRUB.

Comment: Haven't installed arch yet, but i want to try. Heard its super nasty to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, its easy to detect and windows entry to grub if windows partitions were left untouched.

A simple grub-update detected windows.

Comment: I don't think you answered the question: ***if no bootloader currently present?*** although I won't criticize here, mainly because the title is a bit misleading.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, mistake in my part. Edited the title. I kinda figured out the answer by myself.